# How to get Facebook graph API to return all ad campaigns with insights and publisher platform breakdowns

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I want to get insights and breakdowns for all ad campaigns for an account. I am almost certain that I can not get `publisher_platform` from the breakdowns because we are using the `campaigns` Edge. Is there some other method of getting what network/publisher_platform a campaign is being run on?

Request

`act_XXX/campaigns?fields=insights{impressions,account_id,account_currency,spend,cost_per_inline_link_click,actions,website_ctr},effective_status,start_time,stop_time&limit=1&breakdowns=publisher_platform&time_rage={"since":"2018-01-02","until":"2018-02-02"}`

Response

```
  "data": [
    {
      "insights": {
        "data": [
          {
            "impressions": "90",
            "account_id": "111111111111",
            "account_currency": "USD",
            "spend": "0.69",
            "actions": [
              {
                "action_type": "comment",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "photo_view",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "post_reaction",
                "value": "10"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "page_engagement",
                "value": "14"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "post_engagement",
                "value": "14"
              }
            ],
            "date_start": "2018-12-16",
            "date_stop": "2019-01-14"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "MAZDZD",
            "after": "MAZDZD"
          }
        }
      },
      "effective_status": "ACTIVE",
      "start_time": "2019-01-14T12:52:16-0600",
      "stop_time": "2019-01-21T12:52:13-0600",
      "id": "23843254853610607"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUkdVQ1p2ZATVNb01JUE55dU9VWWQ3MmxYTTNkSVRNQlI0alg4N2lzZA2FRZAGNDSzVvcDZAhTEF0RDJoZAWVHT09KTjVTeTBIMVpoQ0lmN3Q2djI3b2E2ek9n",
      "after": "QVFIUkdVQ1p2ZATVNb01JUE55dU9VWWQ3MmxYTTNkSVRNQlI0alg4N2lzZA2FRZAGNDSzVvcDZAhTEF0RDJoZAWVHT09KTjVTeTBIMVpoQ0lmN3Q2djI3b2E2ek9n"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/act_xxxxx/campaigns?access_token=xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I find it extremely frustrating that this request returns a response at all since it is not respecting the `breakdown` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked 8 months ago but answering for people who have the same question.

Use

```
act_XXX/campaigns?fields=insights.fields(<fields>).breakdowns(<breakdowns>)
```

So in your case, it's

```
act_XXX/campaigns?fields=insights.fields(impressions,account_id,account_currency,spend,cost_per_inline_link_click,actions,website_ctr).breakdowns(publisher_platform),effective_status,start_time,stop_time&limit=1&time_rage={"since":"2018-01-02","until":"2018-02-02"}
```